# how to include run as configurations in exported eclipse product

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am exporting eclipse rcp application using "eclipse product export  wizard". I want to redirect console logs into a file.
I am doing the below, which is working fine when I run as a eclipse application. It is not reflecting after export.
[image]

Comment: Not sure I understood question, hopefully my answer helped.

Answer (score 1):

The Run configurations cover how to run something, i.e. they are the part external(ish)* to your application.

In particular, the *Output File* and *Standard Input and Output* settings are ways in the Eclipse development environment to handle redirects of the application.

A quick rundown would be to run the console application like this:

```
$ path/to/app -application com.example.yourname > file.log
```

If the shell you are using is Bash, there is a long bit [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) with further options. [Powershell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection) and [cmd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) on windows have similar options.

Of course, if you want your program to write to a file all the time (with a possible command line argument to specify file), you probably will want to code that yourself.

* The reason I put "ish" on external is that some of the settings, like Configuration and Plug-ins are part of what you export, but Arguments, Tracing and Environment are not.

Comment: My question is, I simply want to save console output into a file in eclipse. How to achieve that ? In attached screenshot I could achieve using the output file field. How to export this configuration to a eclipse product ?

Comment: @suneeloleti sorry, I don't understand. I believe I have answered that question. The console output settings are simply not part of the exported product. I have provided you two alternatives (redirects in shell or just writing code)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it.